# How to connect to the soketi server from outside

Tags: docker, websocket

I installed "soketi" on the server using Docker, according to the instructions on the website [docs.soketi.app](https://docs.soketi.app/getting-started/installation/docker):

`docker run -p 6001:6001 -p 9601:9601 quay.io/soketi/soketi:1.4-16-debian`

I have opened port 6001 in the firewall and the application should be accessible from outside. However, it is impossible to connect with soketi from the outside.

From the curl server itself (curl 127.0.0.1:6001) it tells me OK, so soketi works without any problems.
Logs from the container are also ok (docker logs ).

Place the application behind a proxy?
I will only add that I have Apache(httpd) on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, it turned out that my VPN provider was blocking access.